# Accessing Enclosing Class inside anonymous class

Tags: java

suppose i have a code in java like this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class GUIExercise {
    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setLayout(new BoxLayout(center, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Migz");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD));

        center.add(label);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Click me");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(GUIExercise.this, "Font.ITALIC is " + Font.ITALIC + " and Font.BOLD is " + Font.BOLD + " finally Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD is " + (Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD), "Ni Hao", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        });
        center.add(btn);

        frame.getContentPane().add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(frame.getWidth() + 100, frame.getHeight() + 50);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run () {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

putting GUIExercise.this in the first parameter of showmessagedialog will result in error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context. what must be done? or how can i access the EnclosingClass?

Comment: I still don't see. That code is fine if you assume that `EnclosingClass` should extends `Component`. I can't trust this code. Also the error message is sketch because `this` cannot be the name of a variable.

Comment: oh i forgot that the first parameter of the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog must be a component or container. my class is neither, so i should put the JFrame. well, thank you for explaining :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to use that code in a `static` method. You cannot access an enclosing instance from a `static` context, since there is no instance.

---

<strike>That isn't the problem. The issue is that you are trying to execute the method directly in the body of the class. You can't do that. You'll have to put it in a method, probably the method you are meant to override as part of the `ActionListener` interface.</strike>

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EnclosingClass.this, "Hello");
    }
});
```

(Assuming `EnclosingClass` is a `Component`.)

Comment: oh, i forgot to put my overriden actionPerformed method, im sorry for that but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @MiguelRemulta See my edit. You cannot do that from a `static` method. There is no enclosing instance in that context.